# Radeon 68xx, 69xx cards and support for 10-bit color over displayport

Tags: graphics-card, amd-radeon, displayport, color-depth

10-bit color, aka "Deep Color" is a scheme where 10 bits are used for each color channel. This makes for a 30 bit RGB implementation.

IE: 
red: 10 bits
green: 10 bits
blue: 10 bits
total: 30 bits

For more information, please consult this link
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/RGB_color_model#Beyond_truecolor:_deep_color

Radeon 6000 series cards DO support deep color over HDMI, but HDMI also limits the output resolution to 1920x1200, which is not optimal. I want to know if Deep color is possible over display port with the HD6xxx series graphics cards.

Answer (score 1):

From what I can tell 10bits per channel is only available with the AMD FireGL cards. This is very likely to be a marketing decision to sell more high end (read *expensive*) video cards.

Comment: This is not strictly true, as the 6970 supports deep color over HDMI. (though at a low resolution...) Im not willing to shell out for the FireGl cards =/